# Is dreamspark windows registered for lifetime?

Tags: dreamspark

Is Dreamspark windows (7 pro, 8 pro, 8.1 pro) are registered for lifetime **Or** they are expired after the expiration of dreamspark account???

Comment: Read the terms of the agreement that is diaplayed before every dreamspark download for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The windows Client Editions on Dreamspark do not expire after your account is suspended. This is also the case for all software available on dreamspark Premium.

Windows Client is only available on Dreamspark Premium.